# Will I be notified that BACKUP encountered a CHECKSUM error if I use CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR?

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, checksum

I am in the process of adding the `WITH CHECKSUM` flag on our daily SQL backups, as part of an effort to better ensure data integrity.

I definitely want to *know* if a checksum error is ever encountered, but I also don't want my job to stop dead in the water in the middle of the night; I want it to finish backing up the "bad" database, then continue backing up the other databases on the server.

If I use `BACKUP WITH CHECKSUM, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR`, will it still throw the appropriate error (`SEV 22` or `Error 825` or whatever) that will trigger my associated alert? Or does `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR` suppress this altogether, and I'd only know about the problem if I parse the job step output?

I would simply test it, but I don't have a database with known `CHECKSUM` inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minor change to [Brent Ozar's instructions](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/lets-corrupt-sql-server-database-together/) (I used `SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM` instead of `SET PAGE_VERIFY NONE`), I was able to create a small database with a corrupted page (and therefore a mismatched checksum) in a lab environment, to fully test all the possible backups options.

This gave me the answer to my question: **Yes**, if you do a `BACKUP WITH CHECKSUM, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR`, it will still throw an error, but that error will *not* be `Error: 824, Severity: 24`, it will be `Error: 3043, Severity: 16`.

I don't currently alert on all `Sev 16` errors (would rather not get a page every time someone makes a typo in a query), so I had to add a new alert for `Error 3043` to get notified when this issue occurs.

My final takeaway, then, is: **If you enable backup checksum, makes sure you are also alerting on Error 3043**.

Some additional reading and resources:

- [Possible Media Errors During Backup and Restore (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/possible-media-errors-during-backup-and-restore-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) MS Reference detail about backup checksums
- [Example corrupt database to play with and some backup/restore things to try](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/04/17/example-corrupt-database-to-play-with-and-some-backuprestore-things-to-try/): Originally linked by @eckes, this Paul Randal article has excellent content, but the example is SQL 2005.
- [Brent Ozar: Let’s Corrupt a SQL Server Database Together, Part 1: Clustered Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/lets-corrupt-sql-server-database-together/). Clear examples, thanks Brent for posting this. And if you liked that one, don't miss [Part 2: Nonclustered Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/lets-corrupt-database-together-part-2-nonclustered-indexes/) and [Part 3: Detecting Corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/07/lets-corrupt-database-together-part-3-detecting-corruption/)!
- [Steve Stedman's Database Corruption Challenge](http://stevestedman.com/server-health/database-corruption-challenge/): Increasingly difficult challenges in diagnosing and fixing database corruption. Solutions to each are posted.
- [DBA SE: What types of corruption can DBCC CheckDB miss?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/what-types-of-corruption-can-dbcc-checkdb-miss) The most relevant related question I could find on here.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the complete writeup

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will continue and finish, there is an example in this older blogpost. It also contains a broken database file (for older versions) to play with:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/04/17/example-corrupt-database-to-play-with-and-some-backuprestore-things-to-try/

I think it is actually quite important as a dba to simulate all those cases, I know it from experience with customers it is risky and time consuming if you have to research those methods in a downtime. So kudos for asking. Here is a lunatic/ingenious method to do corruption with SQL:

https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2007/03/10/how-to-create-a-corrupt-database-using-bulk-insert-update-and-bcp-sql-server-as-a-hex-editor.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @eckes, this led me in the right direction. I did get some interesting results I will post in my own answer.